# Paypal notify_url not getting called.

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Paypal notify_url not getting called. When i set it up in my profile under selling tools it works as expected. But i want to set it dynamically in paypal buy button. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on live or on sandbox?  If on sandbox, can you provide the email address of the test sandbox seller account?  What type of payment are you processing?  Some payments do not allow you to pass over the IPN URL in the code.

Comment: buss_vj@gmail.com is sandbox seller account. simple payment (currency $)
Is there any chance its not working on sandbox but will work on lve?